# Why can't I use tab for autocompletion in neovim over SSH?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, arch-linux, vim

When used locally on arch I can easily use tab for auto completion in vim when e.g. filling in a path with deoplete. If I SSH to this computer from my laptop then tab still works for completion. But if I SSH from this computer to an Ubuntu 18.04 (or any version I think) machine then when I type tab it simply inserts a tab. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it so I can use tab over SSH when connected to an Ubuntu server?

All machines I mentioned are also running the exact same vimrc and are all using neovim.

Comment: Do the users also have the same `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, they're all the same.

Comment: Did you need to install any additional plugins or software to use auto completions? If so, have you installed it on the remote machine?

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen yes all of the plugins needed are installed on the remote machine. The vim installations are *identical*

Comment: What does `:imap <Tab>` print on both machines? The same?

Comment: @filbranden Yes it prints exactly the same for each OS.

Comment: From your description, the difference could be between Ubuntu and Arch, rather than anything caused by SSH.  Are you able to test with a local login to a similarly-configured Ubuntu system?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I thought not, but it turns out that it is something related to Ubuntu, it doesn't work directly on a machine either

Comment: In that case, you should update your question to include enough information to demonstrate the problem - such as the exact neovim version, and the contents of your config file(s) - and remove the bits about SSH.

Comment: is there any difference between the output of `stty` on both machines? (try with `stty -a` just to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

I sometime have this kind of behaviour when I have "exotic" TERM variable environment.
Can you try to ssh, then `export TERM=xterm`, and then try again the tab in neovim ?

(I would have added this as a comment but don't have enough internet points yet)

Comment: That makes no difference. If you're getting problems with exotic TERMs you may want to add the terminfo file, you can generate it for your terminal via "infocmp > myterm.terminfo", then import it with "tic -s -x myterm.terminfo"